# Send info to the view from another table with navigation property?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, navigation-properties

This is my models

```
 public class Product
 {
    [Key]
    public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public int PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reading> Reading { get; set; }
}

public class Reading
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public int ReadingValue { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

I can send all products to the view with

```
   return View(db.Products.ToList().Where(product => product.CustomerID == Customer));
```

And I can get the latest ReadingValue if I know the Product SerialNumber

```
        var LatestReading = db.Readings.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).Where(s => s.SerialNumber == SerialNumber).Select(m => m.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I send all the products to the view with the latest ReadingValue for each product?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view model that will hold both the data:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public Reading LatestReading { get; set; }
}
```

Change your view to use the new model with:

```
@model FooViewModel
```

Then send them back in your controller:

```
var model = new FooViewModel();
model.Products = db.Products.ToList().Where(product => product.CustomerID == Customer);
model.LatestReading =  db.Readings.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).Where(s => s.SerialNumber == SerialNumber).Select(m => m.ReadingValue).FirstOrDefault();

return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `Reading` property in `Products` class, you can get the latest ReadingValue in the view:

```
foreach(Product product in Model)
{
    var latestReadingValue = product.Reading.OrderByDescendin(m => m.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    // do what you want here 
}
```

but as hutchonoid points out the better option is creating a ViewModel for it, because having logic in the view is a bad practice, and it doesn't correspond to MVC pattern.